# is it safe to use firebase secret on angular JS for admin updates?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I want to create a user on firebase, add a user profile and set the level property to 5. I want to make sure that no one even the user itself can change the level to another number. Only the admin can do that, the reason why I'm thinking of using $authWithCustomToken();

Is this safe using the firebase secret token on angular?

Comment: As you can see from the answers, there is a lot of concern about putting your Firebase secret in a publicly accessible place. The question remaining is: how do you know that a user is *the administrator*? Once you can specify "this is the administrator" on a code/rules level, you can start securing your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of having custom token is never **ever** use your firebase secret. You have a rule that forbid the change to the level property except for a specific custom token allowing it.

When building a custom token you can add your own data (see [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html)). In your case you can add something like that :

```
{ uid: "MyUniqueId", allowLevelChange: "OK"}
```

and test it in your rules.

Comment: how do i create this custom token? i mean do i have to create a new user for the admin from Email & Password Authentication dashboard. Then create a token from its uid?

Comment: If you already have users, then yes you should create a special user having this kind of capability. You should also look at Leandro's answer as the Bolt compiler can make  the job easier.

Answer (score 2):

The data permissions in Firebase are handled by a set of rules that you apply over authenticated or anonymous users, is important to define all the rules to prevent undesired access. For example you can define that a user can only update its own profile.

You should not put your secret anywhere. Just have a good set of permissions.

They have a new system for defining them called Bolt Compiler that had improved the process a lot.

Comment: yes. im aware that permissions are handled by rules. but i don't know how would i go if i want to update a data without anyone updating it but only the admin.